# Is it possible to have a position absolute div, with fixed elements inside, scale up and down responsivly?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a container with position relative, inside that there is a div with position absolute, and inside that there are fixed div elements.

Is is possible to make the position absolute/fixed divs scale up and down depending on the browser size?

Comment: add your code please

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@media` CSS to change the values of size (widths, heights, top, bottom etc.) of your elements classes at particular screen sizes.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {
    .yourClass {yourStyle: style}
    .otherClass {yourStyle: style}
}
@media only screen and (max-width:570px) {
    .yourClass {yourStyle: style}
    .otherClass {yourStyle: style}
}
```

Comment: In addition, you can also use vw and vh units to specify measurements of the internal divs to scale with the viewport: https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you can use width:"calc" css trick to fix the width; This will give auto responsive run the snippet. Here is the live fiddle also  [fiddleLiveDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/b7xfa9s7/)

```css
.container{
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.div1{
  border:1px solid blue;
  background:#bbb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);/* 40px gap between both sides of the div and the edges of the window */
  height:80px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.div2{
  border:1px solid yellow;
  background:red;
  position:fixed;
  left: 60px;
  width: calc(100% - 120px); /* 60px gap between both sides of the div and the edges of the window */
  height:70px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi that all makes sense but i can't seem it make it work with the code i have - this is the website i'm working on http://datahealthcheck.databarracks.com/2016_NA/#title-page and it's the svg/graphs that i'm trying to apply this to

Comment: Which section you have like those divs ?? Maybe I will take a look on that